# Adding HTTP and HTTPS Social Share Counts for Pintrest

Tags: http, https, count, share

Trying to retain the social share counts after migrating http to https and revert our social proof. I am looking for help from folks who can advise on how to summarize two functions and output the total number of shares in the DIV:

```html
<div id="pin-div">0</div>
```

The function returns the count of HTTP url:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    var url = "<?php $page_url = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; echo $page_url; ?>";
    var apiUrl = "https://api.pinterest.com/v1/urls/count.json?callback=receiveCount&url=" + url;

    $.ajax({
      url: apiUrl,
      success: function(result) {
        $.each(result, function(key, val) {
          console.log(key + " - " + val["receiveCount"]["count"]);
          var shareCount = val["receiveCount"]["count"];
          $("#pin-div").html(shareCount);
        });
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Same code returns the count of HTTPS url:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    var url = "<?php $page_url = "https://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; echo $page_url; ?>";
    var apiUrl = "https://api.pinterest.com/v1/urls/count.json?callback=receiveCount&url=" + url;

    $.ajax({
      url: apiUrl,
      success: function(result) {
        $.each(result, function(key, val) {
          console.log(key + " - " + val["receiveCount"]["count"]);
          var shareCount = val["receiveCount"]["count"];
          $("#pin-div").html(shareCount);
        });
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

What am I missing to sum both results?

Thank you all JS developers and hope this will help thousands of people!